# Volley Android, recuperar resposta do servidor

Tags: android, web-service, restful, volley

Olá, estou usando o Volley para Android para conectar ao meu Webservice, porém eu gostaria de exibir a resposta do servidor independente do Status que retorna o HTTP pelo webservice. explicando melhor:

Quando chamo o webservice e a resposta vem como 200 no Status ele entra no 'onResponse' do Volley e consigo verificar o que retornei, porém ao voltar qualquer outro status ele entra no 'onErrorResponse' e aqui dentro não consigo ver qual a mensagem que retorno do Webservice. sei que pelo 'error' consigo saber o status e alguns erros já mostrar ao usuário, mas precisava exibir algumas informações que só o meu retorno do Webservice possui.

Aqui o código de conexão.

```
StringRequest stringRequisicao = new StringRequest(tipoRequisicao, url+funcao, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String respostaWs) {

            try {

                JSONObject objeto = new JSONObject(respostaWs);
                retorno.onSuccess(objeto);

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                System.out.println("Catch : "+e.getMessage());

            }

        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {

                aviso = Toast.makeText(contexto, "[WSF01] Sem Conexão ou Timeout", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                aviso.show();

            } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {

                aviso = Toast.makeText(contexto, "[WSF02] Falha na autenticação", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                aviso.show();

            } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {

                aviso = Toast.makeText(contexto, "[WSF03] Falha no Servidor", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                aviso.show();

            } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {

                aviso = Toast.makeText(contexto, "[WSF04] Falha na Conexão", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                aviso.show();

            } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {

                aviso = Toast.makeText(contexto, "[WSF05] Falha Parse Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                aviso.show();

            } else {

                aviso = Toast.makeText(contexto, "[WSF06] Falha Não identificada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                aviso.show();

            }
            String erro = "[WSF] ";
            if (error.getMessage() != null){
                erro += error.getMessage().toString().trim();
            }

            if (error.networkResponse != null) {
                erro += " Status: "+error.networkResponse.statusCode;
            }

            System.out.println(error.networkResponse);

            aviso = Toast.makeText(contexto,erro, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            aviso.show();

        }
    })
    {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            String auth = "Basic ";

            if (getCredenciais() != null){
                auth += Base64.encodeToString(getCredenciais().getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
            }

            headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
            headers.put("Authorization", auth);
            headers.put("User-Agent", "Megamil");
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            return getParametros();
        }


    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar o `getMessage()` na sua exception, pode conter a causa do erro.
**Exemplo**

```
 @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
              Toast.makeText(contexto, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show;
.
.
.
```

Veja se esta solução te ajuda.

Comment: então, já faço isso, ele apresenta o erro tratado pelo volley, não a resposta do servidor =/